# TestNG results has unparsable "tags" in it

Tags: testng

I am using Jenkins to run my tests, and i've got these errors after test runs:
`org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected start tag name and not < (position: IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE seen <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\r\n<<... @2:3) ...`

It's because i have some tags in my `testng-results.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
<testng-results ignored="46" total="50" passed="2" failed="2" skipped="0">
=======
<testng-results ignored="9" total="10" passed="1" failed="0" skipped="0">
>>>>>>> refs/remotes/origin/master
=======
<testng-results ignored="3" total="4" passed="1" failed="0" skipped="0">
>>>>>>> branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/tester/test.git
=======
<testng-results ignored="9" total="10" passed="1" failed="0" skipped="0">
>>>>>>> branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/tester/test.git
```

And also got these `line` tags in it:

```
<line>
      <![CDATA[Parameter#1 value, Parameter#2 expected error message, Parameter#3 error message is exist]]>
</line>
```

Does anyone know how or why these tags got into it?

Comment: These are not tags. Looks like you had conflicts when merged your xml file and you did not resolve them properly.

Comment: I'm not merging anything, this is made by Jenkins automatically after test run, i have more tests using the same method, and everything works fine, except this one. I think something is wrong in it, but i don't know what, that's why i 'm asking if somebody can tell me, what can cause this.

Comment: probably your jenkins tries to pull some code and there is a conflict with existing piece.

Comment: Someone did a bad git rebase. Hopefully it wasn't committed to version control